# How to decompress .7z file using nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, 7zip

I would like to use nifi for unpacking compressed .7z catalog.

What I have now in nifi: GetFile procesor -> IdentifyMimeType procesor -> CompressContent procesor set on decompress and use mime.type attribute -> PutFile procesor.

The catalog goes through but it is not unpacked.

I would appreciate your help - I didn't find anything which would work - is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache NiFi does not currently support native `.7z` (de)compression using the [`CompressContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CompressContent/index.html) or [`UnpackContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UnpackContent/index.html) processors.

You can [file a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) requesting this feature to be added. For an immediate solution, you can use an `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to run a command-line tool like [7za.exe](https://www.7-zip.org/) which can accept a filename argument and output the results to a configurable file location or stream the output to STDOUT which is captured in the resulting flowfile content and can be written somewhere with `PutFile`.